# Proof of Abelian group

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

I have run into something I don't understand - a proof that group

$P= \{a+b\sqrt5: a,b \in \Bbb Q\}$ is abelian considering usual addition operator $+$. Authors state that checking if the difference of two elements from $P$ is $\in P$ is enough to prove that. Like this:

$(a+b\sqrt5) - (c+d\sqrt5) = (a-c) + (b-d)\sqrt5 \in P$

Why does this prove that $(P, +)$ is abelian group? I really don't get it.

Comment: That doesn't prove.

Comment: What authors are these?  Can you give us a reference?

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea, just found a pdf somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof assumes as known that the real numbers are an abelian group under addition. In that situation, it is enough to show that $P$ is a subgroup, and for that, it suffices to show that it is not empty (considered obvious, since not explicitly mentioned), and closed under subtraction.

Because then $0 = x-x \in P$ for any $x\in P$, as well as $-x = 0-x \in P$, for all $x\in P$, and $x+y = x - (-y) \in P$ for all $x,y\in P$.

Comment: Yes, makes sense. Exactly what I was looking for. Didn't remember that it's enough to show that it's a subgroup of the real numbers. Thank you.